# I cannot use IF-THEN-ELSE and $_SERVER variables in PHP class definition

Tags: php

```
class MY_CONFIG {
    if ( $_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"] == "127.0.0.1" ) {
        var $default = array( 'foo' => 1, 'bar' => 2 );
    } else {
        var $default = array( 'foo' => 3, 'bar' => 4 );
    }
}
```

I am new to PHP. What's wrong with my code above?

The system keeps saying:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF, expecting T_FUNCTION in C:\wamp\www\test\class.php on line 4

Thanks.

-- Hin

Comment: You cannot have control structures inside a class definition. What do you want to do with `MY_CONFIG`? Also, `var` is a pretty old way (PHP4) of declaring class properties... are you reading any tutorial?

Comment: classes must contain either functions (aka methods) or variable definitions. they cannot contain raw code blocks. Your if() would have to be housed in the object's constructor.

Answer (score 5):

vars in a class definition have to be static. if you need to apply logic to them, it should be in the constructor:

```
class MY_CONFIG {
    var $default = array('foo' => 3, 'bar' => 4);

    public function __construct() {
        if ( $_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"] == "127.0.0.1" ) {
          $this->default = array( 'foo' => 1, 'bar' => 2 );
        }
    }

}
```